# Not able to resolve duplicate class error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I was doing a course in udacity, android studio basics.
During which I encountered an error.
The program is not being able to compile and showing error: **duplicate class: com.example.justjava.MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ^**

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(2);
        displayPrice(2 * 5);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) 
        findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given price on the screen.
     */
    private void displayPrice(int number) {
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) 
        findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);

  priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
    }}
```

Comment: May be you already have an Activity MainActivity.class try to delete that

Comment: Please check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Please paste your AndroidManifest.xml file here for better insights